# segmentation fault in question regarding longest cycle in a graph

Tags: graph, segmentation-fault, depth-first-search

In leetcode problem 2360, for finding the longest cycle in a graph with every node having at most 1 edge.

i have applied DFS (note: there is maximum one outgoing edges in the graph and the node with -1 as an edge does not have any edge). I have implemented the code and its giving right answer in the graphs that does contain a cycle but segmentation fault in graphs with no cycles. kindly help me find the error.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void dfs(vector<int> &edges, vector<int> &vis, vector<int> &dist, int node, int &ans)
{
    vis[node] = 1;

    int nb = edges[node];
    if (!vis[nb] && nb!=-1)
    {
        dist[nb] = dist[node] + 1;
        dfs(edges, vis, dist, nb, ans);
    }
    else if( nb!=-1)
    {
        ans = max(ans, dist[node] -dist[nb]  + 1);
    }
}
int longestCycle(vector<int> &edges)
{
    int n = edges.size();
    vector<int> vis(n, 0), dist(n, 0);
    int ans = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (!vis[i])
        {
            // dist[i] = 1;
            dfs(edges, vis, dist, i, ans);
        }
    }
    return ans;
}

int main() {
    vector<int> edges={2,-1,3,1};
    // vector<int> edges={3,3,4,2,3};
    cout<<longestCycle(edges);
}
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the coding language.  Have you used a debugger to determine where the segmentation fault occurs?

Comment: It is a bad idea to use recursion for a depth first search.  You will run out of memory on larger graphs, especially in your case with so many parameters in the call.

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` Why?

Comment: `vector<int> vis(n, 0)` Why?  A vector of bools will use a fraction of the memory and run faster.